# Angular 6: ERROR TypeError: el.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am creating a simple filter pipe in my app, here is what I have.

filter component:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Pipe({
      name: 'dataFilter'
    })
    export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(value: any[], input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any[]) {
                return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            });
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    }
```

here is componet.html

```
<div class="card movies-list" id="movies-list">
  <div class="card-header movies-list_header">
    <h1>Content:  <small>Best movies of 2010's</small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row movies-list_filter">
      <div class="col-md-2">Filter By</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type='text' [(ngModel)]="listFilter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>filterdbY: {{listFilter}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr class="movies-list_tbheader">
          <td></td>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Realease</th>
          <th>Rating</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="movies-list_data" *ngFor="let movie of movies | dataFilter:listFilter">
          <td>
            <img *ngIf="movie.poster_path" class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
          </td>
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.release_date }}</td>
          <td>{{movie.vote_average}}</td>
          <td>{{movie.overview}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in component.ts I have declared the variable listFilter like this:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  listFilter = '';

-----------
}
```

when I run my app and try to seach some text I get the following error

> ERROR TypeError: el.toLowerCase is not a function

what is wrong with my code? any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not considered "best practice" to use a pipe to filter data. Rather, do it in your component. For example:

```
// Local filter
performFilter(filterBy: string): IMovie[] {
    if (filterBy) {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.movies.filter((movie: IMovie) =>
            movie.title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    } else {
        return this.movies;
    }
}
```

I have a detailed blog post about this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

It details why a pipe should not be used to filter and several different techniques for performing the above filter operation.

BTW ... this code really looks familiar. :-) This is the code from one of my OLD Angular v2 talks ... before we were notified by the team that using pipes in this way was not recommended.

Oh ... and I looked at the link you provided as a comment in the other answer (Which has since been deleted) and the code is NOT the same as you posted above. Here is the "working" code from your link:

```
  transform(value: IProduct[], filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    return filterBy ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
        product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;
}
```

Here is the code from above:

```
  transform(value: any[], input: string) {
    if (input) {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        return value.filter(function (el: any[]) {   // <---- data type!
            return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        });
    }
    return value;
}
```

Notice the data type passed to the filter function is `any[]`. It should just be `any`.

Comment: so if I have multiple components  which require customPipeFilter in my app according to your suggestion I will need to have multiple local pipe instead of reusable pipe component ?

Comment: Nope. Just put this method into a service and call it from any component that needs it.

Comment: And of course you are always welcome to not follow "best practices" and use the filter. You won't run into any real issues unless your list gets long.

Comment: okay , I provided the reference to the guy who answered before that this method works perfect in angular 2 using your tutorial , so he understood and he deleted his answer.

Comment: I updated my post to show you the original code (from that link) and your current code. You may have removed the wrong set of []. It's not the one `value: any[]` but the one that is `el: any[]` that is incorrect. Try removing the `[]` from that one and see if you still have an error.

Comment: this method now I tried in angular 2 works,  but in angular 6 even after removing the last [] stil does not work , I dont why :( I will need to change  to local pipe though, i thought it will work

Comment: can you help out on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527623/error-typeerror-cannot-set-property-paginator-of-undefined