# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a table using table Angular material
for reference I am using this example https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="release">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Release</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.first_air_date}} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.overview}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Component .ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { DatatableComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tv-shows',
  templateUrl: './tv-shows.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tv-shows.component.scss']
})
export class TvShowsComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'id', 'release', 'description'];
  dataSource: any;
  @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;
  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) {
    this.moviesService.getPopularTVShows().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = res.results;
    });
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

when I run my app data are displayed in a table perfectly but I get the following error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined
```

> So nothing works at all  neither sorting , filtering or pagination

I need some help here:

What am I doing wrong in my codes above? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934983/error-error-cannot-set-property-paginator-of-undefined

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The error says that you're trying to assign `this.dataSource.paginator` when `this.dataSource` is still `undefined`. Do the assignment **after** it was initalized.

Also, when you want to use the paginator, sort or a filter, you have to use the `MatTableDataSource` class for it. It's not enough to use raw data as your `dataSource`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.moviesService.getPopularTVShows().subscribe(res => {
    // Use MatTableDataSource for paginator
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.results);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Assign the paginator *after* dataSource is set
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is this.paginator , this.sort are undefined at the time of invoke ngOnInit

Comment: No, I thought so too at first but the error says: `Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined`. So it is trying to set the property 'paginator' of a variable that is undefined. And this is `this.dataSource.paginator`

Comment: I love this answer simple and clear !  Thank KIM , now el perfecto

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. assign new instance to ur dataSource just like below code.`dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Order> = new MatTableDataSource();`
and also thanks to [Kim Kern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4694994/kim-kern) for your explanation

```js
export class OrdersComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'Description', 'Status', 'Date', 'Total Price'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Order> = new MatTableDataSource();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private orderService:OrderService) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class DisplayapplicationsComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private pndService: PndService, private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  listOfApplications: any;
  isTableHasData = true;
  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['apprefno', 'orgname', 'ackowledgeNo', 'contactpersonName'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    if( ms != undefined)
    {
      this.sort = ms;
      this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {  
    if(mp != undefined)
    {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }
      
  }

  setDataSourceAttributes() {    
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource( this.listOfApplications['data']);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;    
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getApplications();
  }
  getApplications = () => {
    let userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    const regex = new RegExp('[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}');
    let inputdata = regex.test(userId) ? { 'panno': userId } : { 'branchCode': this.authService.getBOOffice(), 'applicationstatus': 'P' };
    this.pndService.getApplications(inputdata).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.listOfApplications = response;
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
    if (this.dataSource.filteredData.length > 0) {
      this.isTableHasData = true;
    } else {
      this.isTableHasData = false;
    }
  }

}
```