# ERROR Error: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating  Angular material table using  this example:
https://github.com/marinantonio/angular-mat-table-crud. 
The sample is connecting to the table using { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table'.

For my project i need to used MatTableDataSource from '@angular/material'as a table data connector, once i change the code to use MatTableDataSource  i keep getting 
*TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined*.

There is a repro for my issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rhawr

What am I doing wrong ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.exampleDatabase.getAllIssues()` is async in nature and may take time to complete. But `ngAfterViewInit` is going to be called before that. And since the `dataSource` is set in the `subscribe` block of `this.exampleDatabase.getAllIssues()`, hence the error.

Fix it by moving the code from `ngAfterViewInit` in the `subscribe` block. Something like this:

```
public loadData() {
  this.exampleDatabase = new DataService(this.httpClient);
  this.exampleDatabase.getAllIssues().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    this.dataSource.data = data;
    this.dataLength = data.length;

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  });
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyt5ag?file=src/app/app.component.ts) without the error for your ref.